# Parallel vector/array comparison in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Suppose I want to compare two vectors in C++, like so:

```cpp
// a and b are both vector<int> of the same length
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
  if (a[i] > b[i]) {
    foo();
  }
}
```

but the sizes of the vectors are quite large, and I want to reduce the time taken to do this comparison by parallelizing this operation, so I (naively) throw a pragma on it:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
  if (a[i] > b[i]) {
    foo();
  }
}
```

Trying this out, it doesn't seem like it works. My use case isn't quite as simple as this, and so runs into some OOB errors.

Ideally, I would want something like:

```
Thread 1 checks a[0] > b[0] then does foo();
Thread 2 checks a[1] > b[1] then does foo();
etc.
```

And although it might not be as orderly as 0, 1, 2, ... I'd at least want to make sure a thread is not doing a[3] > b[4], or something.

Could someone clarify how to parallelize this loop to do this kind of comparison?

Comment: "Trying this out, it doesn't seem like it works. My use case isn't quite as simple as this, and so runs into some OOB errors." You're doing things right, so the information you omit with these sentences is key to understanding your problem.

Comment: Works fine [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13b6393366b606d7).

Comment: @Richard: Hopefully, we can distinguish user by id/rep with popup/status bar. but still confusing at first. (I don't even know who receive the notification :-/)

Comment: My issue had to do with nested loops, with the vectors being of uneven length. I forget what the specific issue is now, but I eventually realized that the overhead from parallelization was larger than any actual speedup, so I gave up on using it. Thanks for the sanity check, though.

Comment: @Jarod42: I got a notification just now. I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: @Richard: Could you close the question since it's essentially unanswerable without said details? Have you tried collapse and nowait where appropriate?

Comment: I haven't tried collapse or nowait; I'll give it a try. I can't close the question because I don't think I have enough points to.